# Getting 302 status and too many redirects for valid URL while using httpWebRequest and WebClient class

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi guys need help i am trying to make a console application which checks whether a website is available or not. Also i am trying to get the title of the page.
For doing this i am using HttpWebRequest Class (for getting status) and WebClient class (for getting title).

Note: The page i am trying to get is on a private server.
URl format is **(applicationname-environment.corporation.companyname.com)**
**example: FIFO-dev.corp.tryit.com**

When i try to get the status it is always giving me 401 as its status even though the page is up and running

```
List<int> Web_Status = new List<int>();
foreach (var URL in WEB_URL)
{
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest Web_Test = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://" + URL);
        Web_Test.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        HttpWebResponse Web_response = (HttpWebResponse)Web_Test.GetResponse();
        Web_Status.Add((int)Web_response.StatusCode);
        Web_response.Close();
    }
    catch (System.Net.WebException ex)
    {
        HttpWebResponse Web_response = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
        Web_Status.Add((int)Web_response.StatusCode);
    }
}
```

**Also note while giving url's i am making sure that i am not reentering http://.**

The below code is giving this error

> "System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401)
>   Unauthorized.
>
> at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address,
>   WebRequest& request)
>
> at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address)
>
> at website_monitoring.Get_Title.Title(List`1 WEB_URL) in "

```
string source = "";
List<string> status = new List<string>();
WebClient x = new WebClient();
foreach (var item in WEB_URL)
{
    try
    {
        source = x.DownloadString("http://" + item);
        status.Add(Regex.Match(source, @"\<title\b[^>]*\>\s*(?<Title>[\s\S]*?)\</title\>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups["Title"].Value);
    }
    catch (System.Net.WebException ex)
    {
        status.Add(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

**Sorry guys i cant give the exact url i am trying on.**

---

> This code is working with all the common websites and blogs like
>   "stackoverflow.com","http://understandingarduino.blogspot.in/" and so
>   on.

---

Update 1: following mammago suggestion i was able to handle 4xx issue but now it is giving too many redirects issues while getting title.
i was able to handle 302 status issue by autoredirect property to 1000;

```
List<int> Web_Status = new List<int>();
        foreach (var URL in WEB_URL)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest Web_Test = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://" + URL);

                // Set credentials to use for this request.
                Web_Test.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

                Web_Test.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
                Web_Test.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
                Web_Test.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 1000;
                //Web_Test.UserAgent =
                HttpWebResponse Web_response = (HttpWebResponse)Web_Test.GetResponse();
                Web_Status.Add((int)Web_response.StatusCode);
                Web_response.Close();
            }
            catch (System.Net.WebException ex)
            {
                HttpWebResponse Web_response = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
                Web_Status.Add((int)Web_response.StatusCode);
            }
        }
```

Now all i need help is how to handle auto- redirect issue in this segment

```
string source = "";
        List<string> status = new List<string>();
        WebClient x = new WebClient();

        //letting the website know its a known user who is accessing it (as if website have auto authentication)
        x.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        foreach (var item in WEB_URL)
        {
            try
            {
                source = x.DownloadString("http://" + item);
                status.Add(Regex.Match(source, @"\<title\b[^>]*\>\s*(?<Title>[\s\S]*?)\</title\>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups["Title"].Value);
            }
            catch (System.Net.WebException ex)
            {
                status.Add(ex.ToString());
                //source = x.DownloadString("http://" + ex);
                //status.Add(Regex.Match(source, @"\<title\b[^>]*\>\s*(?<Title>[\s\S]*?)\</title\>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups["Title"].Value);
            }
        }
```

> "System.Net.WebException: Too many automatic redirections were
>   attempted.    at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri
>   address, WebRequest& request)    at
>   System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address)

Comment: How is this question related to Java or PHP?
The exception message says everything, you are not authorized.
Maybe the page requires some sort of authentication via OAuth or other authentication mechanisms.

Comment: it is windows authentication and the user has access to the the page

Comment: Thanks @mammago you were right it was a authentication issue.i added this code "Web_Test.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;" and it is working. But now i am getting 302 and too many redirect issues.